Discrepancy in Calculated Values from Iterative and Vectorized Sine Functions
I am working with a NetCDF file that contains latitude values, and I am attempting to compute the reciprocal of the sine values of latitude. The code I wrote is as follows:
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

data = xr.open_dataset('ERA5_2000_01_01.nc')
lat = data.latitude.values
omega = 7.292e-5

f1 = np.array([2 * omega * np.sin(x * np.pi / 180.0) for x in lat])
f2 = 2 * omega * np.sin(lat * np.pi / 180.0)

diff = 1/f1 - 1/f2
print(diff)

The diff is
[-0.00018776 -0.00050296 -0.00059619 -0.00035761  0.00011444 -0.00065717
 -0.00024923 -0.00060329  0.00018545 -0.00014504 -0.00064833 -0.00043263
  0.00061779  0.00013936 -0.00046115 -0.00041766 -0.0009715   0.0005565
 -0.00034907 -0.00123883 -0.00013027  0.00075469  0.00162418 -0.00066007
 -0.00037552 -0.00189229 -0.00101494  0.00089398  0.00063323  0.00030524
  0.00051748  0.00012772  0.00051868  0.00344283 -0.002541    0.00145573
         nan -0.00145573  0.002541   -0.00344283 -0.00051868 -0.00012772
 -0.00051748 -0.00030524 -0.00063323 -0.00089398  0.00101494  0.00189229
  0.00037552  0.00066007 -0.00162418 -0.00075469  0.00013027  0.00123883
  0.00034907 -0.0005565   0.0009715   0.00041766  0.00046115 -0.00013936
 -0.00061779  0.00043263  0.00064833  0.00014504 -0.00018545  0.00060329
  0.00024923  0.00065717 -0.00011444  0.00035761  0.00059619  0.00050296
  0.00018776]

In this code, I compute f1 by iterating over the latitude values and calculating the sine of each latitude value. In contrast, I compute f2 using the entire array of latitude values directly in a vectorized operation. However, I noticed that the results from f1 and f2 produce different outcomes when I calculate the difference diff = 1/f1 - 1/f2.
I am trying to understand why the two results are different. The data used to reproduce this example is available in this link.

This is due to 3 things:

lat is of type np.float32 so it only has about 6 digits of precision;
1/f1 and 1/f2 results in big numbers;
1/f1 - 1/f2 results in a catastrophic cancellation so most of the precision is loss during this operation.

You can improve the precision by:

converting lat to a 64-bit floating-point array with lat = lat.astype(np.float64);
use a more numerically stable approach to compute the difference, or by using extended precision like double-double (which is not a silver-bullet but a good tread-off between precision and speed), at least from lat to f1 and f2 (so all numbers here but not all number of your real-world application).

Be aware that CPython use 64-bit precision for scalar float values. If you want to analyse the accuracy of the computation beyond 64-bit precision, you can use the decimal module (which slow but good for that).

Thanks. Could you talk a bit more about "using extended precision like double-double"? Currently, I only know convert float32 to the float64 by lat = lat.astype(np.float64)

Double-double is not available in Numpy like any extended precision (besides 80-bit one on some x86 CPUs). You need to implement this yourself. This is a bit tedious to do and should be used with care (only for some specific operations, not a whole program, for sake of performance). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Double-double_arithmetic . Isn't lat.astype(np.float64) already enough for your needs compared to previously?

Yes lat.astype(np.float64) is enough for me. But good to know the Double-double.

Ok. Feel free to validate the question then ;) .
